# Can't install sudo npm install -g loopback-cli on Mac osx 10.13

Tags: node.js, loopback

First: sudo npm install -g loopback-cli

"npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
/Users/user/.node/bin/lb -> /Users/user/.node/lib/node_modules/loopback-cli/bin/loopback-cli.js
+ loopback-cli@4.1.0
updated 1 package in 18.808s"

I got above error message.

Help please.

Comment: I don't really see an error there. Just a warning saying the package is deprecated.

Comment: Thats a warning as `WARN` says... and never install npm packages with sudo, its not recommended.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I finally spot and got it working. Thanks.